# laravel form is not working even after every particular step

Tags: laravel

In composer.json
        require {
           "laravelcollective/html": "^5.5"
        }

```
{!! Form::open(['route' => 'blogs.store']) !!}
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="form-group">
     {!! Form::label('title', 'Blog Title') !!}
     {!! Form::text('title', null,['class'=>'form-control']) !!}
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
     {!! Form::label('body', 'Blog Body') !!}
     {!! Form::textarea('body', null,['class'=>'form-control']) !!}
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
     {!! Form::submit('Add Blog', ['class'=>'btn btn-primary']) !!}
    </div>
  </div>

{!! Form::close() !!}
```

In Controller

```
public function store(BlogRequest $request)
{
   $input = Request::all();
   Blog::create($input);
   return redirect(blogs);         
}
```

provider in app

Collective\Html\HtmlServiceProvider::class,

aliases in app

```
'Form' => Collective\Html\FormFacade::class,
'Html' => Collective\Html\HtmlFacade::class,
```

form not working apart after submitting it show value in address bar this is what it shows

```
http://localhost/lynda/blogs/create?_token=dIQXrWadbNNJhCBMUYjUAAOM1MPXDmhD782rlJ0F&title=aaaaa&body=aaaa
```

Comment: Please clear the cache and run this command : 1) php artisan config:cache 2) php artisan cache:clear

Comment: And please give me error

Comment: did you run `composer update` after update composer.json ? if already then try `composer dump-autoload` and then `composer update`

Comment: `form not working` is not an error message anyone can help you with.  What is not working?  What happened, and what did you expect to happen?

Answer (score 0):

You should try this:

1) First run composer update for update your `html` package after run `composer dump-autoload` in terminal/cmd

2) Please clear the cache and run this command in terminal/cmd

```
php artisan config:cache 

php artisan cache:clear
```

3)

```
        public function store(BlogRequest $request)
        {
            $input = $request->all();
            Blog::create($input);
          return redirect('blogs');

        }
```

Comment: @MohammadMaroofMalik: Please dd($input);exit; and check which value given

Answer (score 0):

Please add a method to your form. If you don't have method, it will use get method.

```
{!! Form::open(['method' => 'post', 'route' => 'blogs.store']) !!}
```

Comment: http://localhost/lynda/blogs/create?_token=dIQXrWadbNNJhCBMUYjUAAOM1MPXDmhD782rlJ0F&title=aaaaa&body=aaaa its still not working this what it show in adressbar

Comment: Did you set your route with a post method, and dont forget to add post method in the form.